# Pass context in 'persist' to 'after save'

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I need to pass context from a Operation Hook (persist) to another (after save), I know the [existence](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/Operation+hooks#Operationhooks-SharedhookStateproperty) of the `ctx.hookState` but its not working.

```
ZZ.observe('persist', (ctx, next) => {
      ctx.hookState = "pass this";
      next();
    }).catch(err => next(err));
  });

ZZ.observe('after save', (ctx, next) => {
  console.log(ctx.hookState);
  next()
});
```

I don't get anything in `console.log(ctx.hookState)`. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't overwrite `hookState`

You can do like this :

```
ZZ.observe('persist', (ctx, next) => {
      ctx.hookState.foo = "pass this";
      next();    
  });

ZZ.observe('after save', (ctx, next) => {
  console.log(ctx.hookState.foo);
  next()
});
```

Comment: Yeah, make all sense! Thank you.